# Ways in which number of flags can be generated.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Find the number of different signals that can be given with six flags of different colours hoisted one below the other ***by using any number of flags***?

Attempt:

Let's consider "no choice" also as a choice,
thus, number of ways = $6 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times3 \times 2 = 4320$ (because there must be at least one flag)  but the answer given is $1956$.

How do I solve it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Given that any number of flags can be hoisted at a time, we need to find out the number of signals that can be made using $1$ flag, $2$ flags, $3$ flags, $4$ flags, $5$ flags and $6$ flags and then add all these. Thus, our required sum is: $$\sum_{k=1}^{6} {^{6}}P_{k}=\, \,?$$

Comment: (+1) Got it! Btw, is there any formula to calculate that sum directly?

Comment: @Abcd Not that I know of, but the calculation is simple indeed.

Comment: yes, here it is.